# CSS Transitions Not working after toggleClass()

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I created a toggle-menu, as shown in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/85Ryan/Hrsdw/1/).

I addded a css transition effect for `div.nav-menu`, and i used `max-height:0;` to `max-height:480px;`.

When I click the menu toggle to show the menu, the transition works well. But when I click the menu toggle to hide the menu again the transition doesn't work.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are wrong about CSS Transitions. They **do not animate when you add or remove class**, It will only animate when you **change the CSS properties**. *And You are directly adding and removing classes.*

Here is your solution:

```
$( '.menu-toggle' ).on( 'click', function() {
    if(nav.hasClass('toggled-on')) {
       menu.css('maxHeight', 0);
       //^ Here is changed the 'max-height` first so that the 
       //  Transition animation will trigger first
    }
    else menu.css('maxHeight', '480px'); 
         // ^ If not I changed it back to 480px;
} );

// Next I bind on the transaction end event of the element to toggle class
// After it finishes the transistion

menu.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
    nav.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hrsdw/7/)

Comment: thanks! but it still has a problem! because you add `max-height=0;` to the `.nav-menu` , when click the toggle to hide the menu, the style still exists. so it can only run one cycle, and not keep doing the loop.

Comment: Thank you for helping me modify the error in my question, my english is very poor! :)

Comment: @85Ryan, Please see my updated answer. I have updated your `nav-menu ul` styles to show without the toggled-on class and now everything is working as it should. :)

Comment: I got it! Thanks and you missed a `{`

Comment: @Starx I guess you are not 100% right about `They **do not animate when you add or remove class**`. Because if you change the class, and the new class change CSS Propertie, the `transition` will work as well. Look this > [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Hrsdw/30/). I just change a little bit his CSS.

Comment: you are saying adding class does not trigger transition, but it does, the problem is removing class does not trigger .

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to get the effect you're after.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Hrsdw/3/)**

js

```
$(function() {
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
        if($('.nav-menu').is(':hidden')){ // check to see if menu is hidden
            $('.nav-menu').slideDown();}  // if so slide down
        else{$('.nav-menu').slideUp();}   // else slide up
    });
});
```

css

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
    max-width: 860px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 45px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.menu-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 16px/1.3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.nav-menu {

    margin: 0;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-menu ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.nav-menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding:10px;color:#fff;line-height:1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-menu li a:hover,.nav-menu li a:focus{background:#272727;}
.toggled-on li a:active{background:#2A8A15;}
```

[API for .slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [API for .slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Comment: Do you understand the question is about CSS Transition?

Comment: @Starx Yes I understand the question, just thought the op may be interested in a short cut to the same goal. Also your solution only seems to work once... Try clicking the menu again after its been hidden.

Comment: You seem to be wrong about me. I was not commenting on your question to make my answer right. :)

Comment: @Starx Its all good, check out this meta post for a good laugh on the subject http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179567/217863

Comment: Also, If i thought your answer was wrong, I would have downvoted you. You are correct dude!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using max-height use height

```
.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    height:0;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transition:all 350ms cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    -ms-transition:all 350ms cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    -o-transition:all 350ms cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    -webkit-transition:all 350ms cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    transition:all 350ms cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
}
.toggled-on .nav-menu {
    display: block;
    height:480px;
}
```