# Trying to trigger a CSS transition using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, listener, css-transitions, innerhtml

Playing with JavaScript and CSS transition, I tried to remove a CSS class
right after having dynamically inserted a div, using JavaScript and innerHTML.

I'm really surprised to see that the CSS transition associated with the opacity of the blue div is not triggered the way I want (works under Safari, works randomly under Chrome, doesn't work under Firefox Dev Edition). Can someone explain this phenomenon ?

I'm not sure about why it is not working the same way as it does for the red div. Maybe something I don't know about how browsers handle innerHTML ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Having fun with JS</title>
    <style>
        .std {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: opacity 5s;
        }

        .std--hidden {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .std--red {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .std--blue {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<button>click here</button>
<div class='std std--red std--hidden'></div>
<div class='insert-here'>
</div>
<script>
    // let a chance to the browser to trigger a rendering event before the class is toggled
    // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4575011
    setTimeout(function() {
        // everything works fine for the red div
        document.querySelector('.std--red').classList.toggle('std--hidden');
    }, 0);


    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        var template = `<div class='std std--blue std--hidden'></div>`;
        document.querySelector('.insert-here').innerHTML = template;

        setTimeout(function() {
            // Why does the CSS transition seems to be triggered randomly ?
            // well more exactly
            // - it works under my Safari
            // - it does not work under my FirefoxDeveloperEdition
            // - it works randomly under my Google Chrome
            document.querySelector('.std--blue').classList.toggle('std--hidden');
        }, 0);

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## EDIT

So I've just read the [CSS transitions specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property) and found this

> This processing of a set of simultaneous style changes is called a
>   style change event. (Implementations typically have a style change
>   event to correspond with their desired screen refresh rate, and when
>   up-to-date computed style or layout information is needed for a script
>   API that depends on it.)

Can this be the explanation somehow ? Does the setTimeout 0 is too fast on some browsers that they don't have time to compute the style differences and thus don't trigger a style change event ? Indeed if use a longer setTimeout (say, ~16.6666, guessing a 1/60 refresh rate...) it seems to work everywhere. Can someone confirm that ?

Comment: What's the point of using `setTimeout`? It isn't doing anything. Maybe try removing them and see what happens?

Comment: Yes it is useful, it queues the code removing the css class after that the browser has first rendered the DOM

Comment: Try removing the backtick where you inserted the inner HTML elements in your `var template`. and see instead add double quotes ""

Comment: oooh... tha backtick doesn't do anything... you should probably be using double quotes (`"`) for the outside and single quotes (`'`) for the `class=`

Comment: The backtick corresponds to an ES6 template string.

Comment: ES6 is not fully supported in browsers. Are you sure the ES6 features you are using are supported in each browser?

Comment: Template strings are ok of you use modern browsers, see http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Template strings work in all of the browser's he's targeting.

Comment: I've created a Fiddle if anyone needs one: https://jsfiddle.net/e3grdg4m/. I'm also not able to reproduce the issue in Chrome: it works correctly there.

Comment: Don't use fiddles or so. I works on fiddle's but not outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found the answer, see the [CSS 3 transition spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#style-change-event):

> Since this specification does not define when a style change event
>   occurs, and thus what changes to computed values are considered
>   simultaneous, authors should be aware that changing any of the
>   transition properties a small amount of time after making a change
>   that might transition can result in behavior that varies between
>   implementations, since the changes might be considered simultaneous in
>   some implementations but not others.

I tried to add a little delay to let the browsers notice the style differences and it works consistently. It seems that some browsers are executing a setTimeout 0 really faster than others :-)

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('.std--blue').classList.toggle('std--hidden');
    }, 17);
```

Answer (score 1):

To trigger a transition you don't really need a class to toggle. This is important since you may not be able to set up classes dynamically to toggle beforehand. In other words you may just need to alter some CSS attributes to trigger the transitions. However yes... you need to satisfy the followings;

1. In order your `<div id="blue"></div>` element to animate, it must carry the `std` class where the `transition` is defined. So first we should do like `blue.classList.add("std");`
2. You need to perform the task asynchronously. Refreshing the DOM asynchronously is best done by the `requestAnimationFrame()` function.

```js
var blue = document.getElementById("blue");
blue.classList.add("std");
blue.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
blue.style.opacity         = 0;

document.querySelector('button')
        .addEventListener( 'click'
                         , _ => requestAnimationFrame(_ => blue.style.opacity = 1)
                         );
```

```css
.std { width:100px;
       height:100px;
       opacity: 1;
       transition: opacity 5s;
}
.std--red { background-color: red;}
```

```html
<button>click here</button>
<div class='std std--red'></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to trigger the transition by making a reference to the style. I simply added this line (even into console.log is ok)

```
document.querySelector('.std.std--blue').style.width = '20';
```

and here it works: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/ymg8f1ts/1/)

NB: I am using FirefoxDeveloperEdition.

I have followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17518469/4334348):

> CSS Transitions do not animate when you add or remove class, It will only animate when you change the CSS properties.

**Complete script**

```
<script>

setTimeout(function() {
    // everything works fine for the red div
    document.querySelector('.std--red').classList.toggle('std--hidden');
}, 0);


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var template = `<div class='std std--blue std--hidden'></div>`;
    document.querySelector('.insert-here').innerHTML = template;
    document.querySelector('.std.std--blue').style.width = '20';
    setTimeout(function() {

        document.querySelector('.std.std--blue').style.width = '100';
        document.querySelector('.std--blue').classList.toggle('std--hidden');
    }, 0);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try it outside fiddle (or alike), directly inside a browser, it doesn't work for me. But it works inside fiddle, codepen, etc...

Comment: That's not true, the first animation is triggered.

Comment: Your code does not seem to answer my question about why does it work for the red div but not for the blue div ?

Comment: CSS Transitions do not animate when you add or remove class, It will only animate when you change the CSS properties.  I added it also in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You must set a value to the timeout so you give time for the element to be inserted in the DOM (must exist before calling `document.querySelector`)

```
setTimeout(function() { document.querySelector('.std--blue').classList.toggle('std--hidden')},100);
```

you don't need the first timeout

```js
onload = function() {
document.querySelector('.std--red').classList.toggle('std--hidden');

 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   var template = "<div class='std std--blue std--hidden'></div>";
   document.querySelector('.insert-here').innerHTML = template;
   setTimeout(function() { document.querySelector('.std--blue').classList.toggle('std--hidden')},100);
    });
}
```

```css
 .std {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: opacity 5s;
        }

        .std--hidden {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .std--red {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .std--blue {
            background-color: blue;
        }
```

```html
<button>click here</button>
<div class='std std--red std--hidden'></div>
<div class='insert-here'>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I can't accept your answer as it does not answer the question. I know that I can change the delay, I just don't understand why it doesn't work in the second case.

Comment: If you try running the code outside of jsfiddle (open the HTML inside a browser), do you see the first animation if you don't place a setTimeout ? I don't.

Comment: Yes code runs on document Load, tested in IE11, Firefox, Chrome and Chrome Canary

Comment: On my computer it works under Safari Version 9.0.3 (11601.4.4) but is working randomly under Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit) and doesn't work under Firefox Dev Edition 46.0a2 (2016-03-04). :-(

Comment: try to wrap your code in an event listener `onload = function() { //code }`
  }

Comment: No effect on my browsers. Why would that change something anyway ? For the blue div I mean.

Comment: It's unusual you don't see the transition, have you tried a cross browser test in virtual browsers? like browserstack.com?

Comment: I've added an edit to my question. Found that there is a slight delay that the browsers need to recompute the style differences. Maybe it's the real culprit ? Because it looks like something doesn't (or sometimes doesn't ) have enough time to notice that the opacity property changed. If I give it a little more time (say 1/60s), that works consistently.